# Future or past, depending on the country

Tags: riddle, language

> Depending on the country,
>
> I either describe the future or the past
>
> When describing the past, I am usually kept secret
>
> I am also used during a meeting, but sometimes I contain a meeting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be:

> An agenda

Depending on the country

> The word has different meanings in different countries

I either describe the future

> An agenda can be a list of things to do in the future

or the past

> In Spanish/French agenda means diary, a personal record of the past

When describing the past, I am usually kept secret

> Most people write personal things in their diaries, and so prefer to keep them secret.

I am also used during a meeting, but sometimes I contain a meeting.

> You use an agenda during a meeting to have a list of things to discuss, but an item on an agenda could also be to have a meeting in the future.

Comment: You have the correct answer, but first three clues are not what I meant – there are better fitting explainations. Hence I will not yet accept this. There is a [tag:language] tag on the question, this might help with the first three clues.

Comment: Good point, missed the language tag. Gave it another shot.

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: *Agenda* in French does not mean diary, but, well, agenda. Personal organizer, day planner, whatever you call it. You can certainly write stuff you already did in it, but that’s not the main point.

Comment: wiktionary only lists the wanted definition in Italian, but neither French nor Spanish.

Answer (score 9):

I think the word is

> Kal

Depending on the country,

I either describe the future or the past

> In Hindi language, both yesterday and tomorrow are called 'kal'.

When describing the past, I am usually kept secret

> In Lithuanian language, 'kal' means prison. And no one wants to say that they have gone to prison in the past.

I am also used during a meeting, but sometimes I contain a meeting.

> In Arabic, 'kal' means 'to speak'. We speak in meetings. And in Yoruba, 'kal' means 'institutes'. Meeting happens in institutes too.

Comment: That is not the intended solution, but actually fits the clues quite good.

Answer (score 4):

My answer would be :

> A DATE

Depending on the country,

I either describe the future or the past

> Due to the difference in timezone a date may be future or a past

When describing the past, I am usually kept secret

> Many times we don't mention the date and replace it with the other day or day before or day after

I am also used during a meeting, but sometimes I contain a meeting.

> Date contains a meeting in the calendar and it is used in the meeting to mention the proximity of the deliverable.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with the site. Answers are usually hidden by spoilers, you can make them using >!. I suggested an edit to fix this. The answer is actually reasonable, however, I don't see the relation to the third clue, or the [tag:language] tag.

Comment: Also, a certain moment in time can describe either the past or the future depending on which time zone. (I think you meant this, but it is not in the answer)

Comment: I hope the edit is correct and thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Your edit improved your answer's content quite a bit, but a few things went wrong when you edited, mainly the use of both spoilers and quotes. Removing the quotes (>) fixed the problem. I suggested an edit to fix it (you can approve it by clicking on the edit link). Also, regarding the edit you suggested on the question: Please don't, since [tag:language] is also a clue.